# How to load external (remote) Markdown files into Docusaurus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, docusaurus, mdxjs

Seems like a very basic question, but I could not find an answer in SO, docs or GH issues:

We are transferring an existing doc site to Docusaurus V2. Many of our `.md` files are stored across different GH repos (=different URLs), and we'd like to link and load them inDocusaurus. In our current setup, we achive that using an Axios GET request to each `md` remote URL and use `ReactMarkdown` to load its content.

In Docusaurus, is there a way to load remote `md` by simply providing their URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using https://github.com/rdilweb/docusaurus-plugin-remote-content

On Docusaurus v2 using a plugin that downloads content from remote sources.

With this plugin, you can write the Markdown for your docs and blog somewhere else, and use them on your Docusaurus site.

Comment: Is there a way to pull data from other repository?